# Deletting duplicate data on oracle using sql failed

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table **`abc`** as:

```
acc   subgroup
720V  A
720V  A
720V  A
720V  A
111   C
222   D
333   E
```

My expected output is:

```
    acc   subgroup
    720V  A
    111   C
    222   D
    333   E
```

Since `720V A` is duplicate i want to delete all three duplicate data and only want one data in my table.
So,i tried

```
DELETE FROM (
select t.*,rownum rn from abc  t where acc='720V') where rn>1;
```

So,I get error as:

```
ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
```

How i can get my expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table seems to be lacking a primary key column, which is a big problem here.  Assuming there actually *is* a primary key column `PK`, we can try using `ROW_NUMBER` to identify any "duplictes":

```
DELETE
FROM abc t1
WHERE pk IN (SELECT pk
             FROM (
                 SELECT t.pk, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acc, subgroup ORDER BY pk) rn
                 FROM abc t) x
             WHERE rn > 1
);
```

Note that if you can live with keeping your original data, then the most expedient thing to do might be to create a distinct view:

```
CREATE VIEW abc_view AS
SELECT DISTINCT acc, subgroup
FROM abc;
```